# How to Take Advantage of Scrapy's Concurrency With Non-Selenium Requests

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I've got an interesting problem here.  I'm writing a Scrapy web scraper to obtain products off of a website.  The catalog pages use lazy-loading, which means I cannot obtain more than the first 12 items or use pagination using the default Scrapy.  I have started using Selenium with a headless chrome client in order to scroll the page manually to obtain the data.

I have read online that using Scrapy + Selenium means that I can't run Scrapy requests concurrently, which is unfortunate because the vast majority of my requests don't require Selenium.  My selenium middleware checks the request.meta property to see if it needs to do anything, otherwise it simply returns None.  However, all requests are filtered through the middleware.

My question is  this: Is there a way to allow those requests that DON'T require Selenium to be run concurrently?

My middleware:

```
def __init__(self):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/driver", chrome_options=options)

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if request.meta.get("selenium"):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        ... # Perform selinium scroll logic and return body
    return None
```

My spider parse function:

```
def parse(self, response):
    meta = {"otherMetaData": "data", "selenium": True}
    ... # Obtain link to catalog page
    yield response.follow(page_link, callback=self.parseProducts, meta=meta)

def parseProducts(self, response):
    ... # Obtain links to product pages
    response.meta.pop("selenium")
    yield response.follow(page_link, callback=self.parseProductPage, response.meta)
```

EDIT: Formatting

Answer (score 0):

This was an Issue I faced recently, what you need to know is that Scrapy relies on the scheduler to issue the timing of the requests, The scheduler waits until the value of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` (this value will be skipped if there are less amount of requests to be made i.e when spider is finishing up final requests) is reached then it will make it's requests, the scheduler also depends on `priority` which you can modify to give certain links higher priority to make them launch earlier in the queue.

There is no direct way of doing what you are asking for,but a good way to do it would be to pass your "non-selenium" requests to a different spider with it's own `custom_settings`